# Avoid Mean of Floating Point Error

Tags: python, floating-point

When I calculate the mean of a list of `float`s the following way

```py
def mean(x):
    sum(x) / len(x)
```

then I usually do not care about tiny errors in floating point operations. Though, I am currently facing an issue where I want to get all elements in a `list` that are **equal or above** the list's average.

Again, this is usually no issue but when I face cases where all elements in the list are *equal floating point numbers* than the mean value calculated by the function above actually returns a value *above* all the elements. That, in my case, obviously is an issue.

I need a workaround to that involving no reliability on python3.x libraries (like e.g. statistics).

**Edit:**
It has been suggested in the comments to use rounding. This interestingly resulted in errors being rarer, but they still occur, as e.g. in this case:

```py
[0.024484987, 0.024484987, 0.024484987, 0.024484987, ...]  # x
0.024485  # mean
[]  # numbers above mean
```

Comment: is rounding up to certain precision acceptable?

Comment: @CrowbarKZ yes it is

Comment: then calculating it as e.g. `round(sum(x) / len(x), 6)` should do it, as long as you do not need big precision, @weidler

Comment: @CrowbarKZ This sadly doesn't resolve the issue, while it interestingly makes it less frequent. I'll add an example to the original question.

Comment: Ok, but rounding the single elements as well when comparing did the trick. thanks!

Comment: Are the numbers in the list the result of prior calculations? If so, do not they already having various rounding errors, some up and some down? That would mean that, even if you calculated the mean exactly and used it to select numbers not below the mean, the results would differ from the ideal mathematical results because some of the numbers would be falsely below the mean due to having been rounded down and some would be falsely above the mean due to having been rounded up.

Comment: There are techniques for computing floating-point sums [with enhanced accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) or [exactly](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/393090-binary-floating-point-summation-accurate-to-full-p/). Once you had the exact sum, it could be rounded to a floating-point value and then divided by the number of elements. This would produce an estimate of the mean with error slightly greater than ½ ULP. Unfortunately, even if the error could be limited to the “ideal” ½ ULP, I do not think Python lets us control the rounding direction.…

Comment: … This means, in calculating the mean, the quotient may be rounded up or down during the division, and it is difficult to know which. We would need to know which because, if it is rounded up, then any value *x* in the list greater than or equal to the calculated mean is greater than or equal to the ideal mean, and, if it is rounded down, then any value *x* in the list greater than the calculated mean is greater than or equal to the ideal mean. So we need to know the rounding to know the appropriate test to use, or we need to control the rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should be using `math.fsum()` instead of `sum`. For example:

```
>>> a = [0.024484987, 0.024484987, 0.024484987, 0.024484987] * 1360001
>>> math.fsum(a) / len(a)
0.024484987
```

This is, I believe, the answer you are looking for. It produces more consistent results, irrespective of the length of `a`, than the equivalent using `sum()`.

```
>>> sum(a) / len(a)
0.024484987003073517
```

Comment: `math.fsum` provides more accuracy but not exactness on some platforms. In addition, the division must be performed to compute the mean, and this introduces another rounding error. Hence it will reduce the frequency of errors but not eliminate them.

Comment: I did say *more consistent*, not *fully accurate*. For accuracy there is always the Decimal class.

Comment: Decimal is not exact. Adding Decimal values with different exponents has rounding errors (unless enough low digits of the lesser magnitude value are zero). Dividing in Decimal has rounding errors unless the divisor is a power of ten.

Comment: You are of course quite right about dividing in `Decimal`. But `Decimal`  gives you more control over the rounding than `float` does.

Comment: Note that `fsum` doesn't solve the problem of error in the division: e.g. try `math.fsum([0.4309614612208263 for x in range(10)])/10`

Comment: or even `[0.2,0.2,0.2]`

Answer (score 1):

One neat solution is to use [compensated summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), combined with [double-double tricks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic) to perform the division accurately:

```
def mean_kbn(X):
    # 1. Kahan-Babuska-Neumaier summation
    s = c = 0.0
    n = 0
    for x in X:
        t = s + x
        if abs(s) >= abs(x):
            c -= ((s-t) + x)
        else:
            c -= ((x-t) + s)
        s = t
        n += 1
    # sum is now s - c

    # 2. double-double division from Dekker (1971)
    # https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01397083 
    u = s / n # first guess of division

    # Python doesn't have an fma function, so do mul2 via Veltkamp splitting
    v = 1.34217729e8 #  0x1p27 + 1 
    uv = u*v
    u_hi = (u - uv) + uv
    u_lo = u - u_hi
    nv = n*v
    n_hi = (n - nv) + nv
    n_lo = n - n_hi
    # r = s - u*n exactly
    r = (((s - u_hi*n_hi) - u_hi*n_lo) - u_lo*n_hi) - u_lo*n_lo
    # add correction
    return u + (r-c)/n
```

Here's a sample case I found, comparing with the `sum`, `math.fsum` and `numpy.mean`:

```
>>> mean_kbn([0.2,0.2,0.2])
0.2
>>> sum([0.2,0.2,0.2])/3
0.20000000000000004
>>> import math
>>> math.fsum([0.2,0.2,0.2])/3
0.20000000000000004
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.mean([0.2,0.2,0.2])
0.20000000000000004
```

Answer (score -1):

How about not using the mean but just multiplying each element by the length of the list and comparing it directly to the sum of the original list?
I think this should do what you want without relying on division